# What is wrong with this Windows Batch code?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

```
REM test.bat

@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~1" == "" IF NOT "%~2" == "" (
    SET /A "X=%~1+%~2"
    echo %X%
)
```

Instead of getting the sum of the two numbers, it always prints the previous value of `X`:

```
>test.bat 1 2
ECHO is off

>test.bat 3 4
3

>test.bat 4 4
7
```

Is that because I'm not using `EnableDelayedExpansion`?

**Edit:** Why does it work when I move the echo out of the scope?

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~1" == "" IF NOT "%~2" == "" (
    SET /A "X=%~1+%~2"
    GOTO why
)
GOTO :EOF

:why
echo %X%
```

Comment: Is that because I'm not using EnableDelayedExpansion? -Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed the delayed expansion - I suppose you know how to fix it - the only (afaik) reason to want to avoid it's usage is if you want the variables to survive endlocal statement and to use the variable value in brackets context meanwhile .So you can use additional CALL or tunneling:

```
@ECHO OFF
:: using call
IF NOT "%~1" == "" IF NOT "%~2" == "" (
    SET /A "X=%~1+%~2"
    call echo %%X%%
)

@ECHO OFF
:: using tunneling
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
IF NOT "%~1" == "" IF NOT "%~2" == "" (
    SET /A "X=%~1+%~2"
    rem echo !X!
)
endlocal & set x=%x%
echo %x%
```

**EDIT WAS MADE**
The call starts a new sub-context of the command prompts with inherited variables.Additional %s are used to expand the variable in the next level.

Why does it work when I move the echo out of the scope?

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~1" == "" IF NOT "%~2" == "" (
    SET /A "X=%~1+%~2"
    GOTO why
)
GOTO :EOF

:why
echo %X%
```

GOTO breaks the brackets context ,but in this case even without GOTO the correct value of the %x% will be printed because is outside of the brackets.